# Jquery Hover function modification

Tags: jquery

I have implemented a hover function so that when you hover over a star this and all previous siblings have a addclass method applied to them

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ratings li').hover(function(){
  $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
 });
});
```

What happens at the moment is if i hover over say the fourth star (there are 5) then the foruth and all siblings have the class applied.

What i want to achieve  is that when i leave the hover state the li goes back to its original state, or even better the hover follows the flow of the mouse, so as i hover over the li's the class is applied (hope that makes sense)

I have put together a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/vZDwg/2/) but for some reason the image isnt showing, even though the path is public?

Comment: thanks all, didnt think to just add another function.... will from now on though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ratings li').hover(function(){
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
    // add a function for when the hover ends...
    },function(){
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().removeClass('goldstar');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5T0M.png");
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vZDwg/3/)

Comment: poo, its broken my click method now :(  not your fault though, something else to look at now for me

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
 $('.ratings li').hover(function(){
   $(this).prevAll().addBack().addClass('goldstar');
 }, function(){
   $('.ratings li').removeClass('goldstar');
 });
```

Note that I replaced `andSelf` which is deprecated by `addBack`. You may let `andSelf` if you use an old jQuery version.

You might also be interested by how I circumvented the image problem...

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/yvVDE/)

Comment: interesting way of solving the image problem :)

Comment: Unicode is full of assets for many common interface problems :)

Comment: I like your use of unicode... is there a danger it might not be displayed on iPad etc... are there any safe fallbacks?

Comment: I frequently use this solution (not for stars but for example for triangles). I you use a standard (specified) font and a not too exotic character, the risk is low (in fact I had no problem until now).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ratings li').hover(function(){
 function () {
    // Run on Mouse over
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
  },
  function () {
    // Run on Mouse out
    $(this).removeClass('goldstar');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: when moving off the list, this will leave one less star than where you left off

Answer (score 1):

Clear the class from the stars after your mouse [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vZDwg/6/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ratings li').hover(function(){
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('goldstar');
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
    });
    $('.ratings ul').mouseout(function(){
       $('li', this).removeClass('goldstar'); 
    });
  });
```

UPDATED: remove all stars on mouseout

Comment: this will leave the stars showing if you move your mouse off the list (not onto another `li`)